# Can't Access Attachment Data In Google Plus JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, google-plus

I am accessing the Google Plus API and this is one of the results that are returned:

```
{
 "nextPageToken": "Ci8I0bJLEie2uAPcvrABl96xAdaVqgO93LADn_6ABO2vgwXqpbAFoNmEBsHCpwgYAgovCJXLThInn-8054qFArGHmQKtp-gD_r6-BOqlsAW-7uAGjO7QB4HbngqEoKkLGAEQj5e7jAUY8sK7jAUiAA",
 "items": [
  {
   "id": "z13rwjqhyqzve5tgq04cdxfyfzqtgfszfcw",
   "url": "https://plus.google.com/104261567553968048744/posts/SDs5inGSpEi",
   "actor": {
    "displayName": "Evan Parker",
    "url": "https://plus.google.com/104261567553968048744"
   },
   "verb": "post",
   "object": {
    "attachments": [
     {
      "objectType": "photo",
      "displayName": "#throughglass",
      "id": "104261567553968048744.5876882440165641794",
      "content": "s_00d2c678-b686-49db-9666-a55292cbe59b-0",
      "url": "https://plus.google.com/photos/104261567553968048744/albums/5876882440813674497/5876882440165641794?authkey=CM3iyKyWoa7gcA",
      "image": {
       "url": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-aI28I0V0geM/UY7hcTjNzkI/AAAAAAABzYw/8MxNghGljew/w497-h373/s_00d2c678-b686-49db-9666-a55292cbe59b-0",
       "type": "image/jpeg",
       "height": 373,
       "width": 497
      },
      "fullImage": {
       "url": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-aI28I0V0geM/UY7hcTjNzkI/AAAAAAABzYw/8MxNghGljew/s0-d/s_00d2c678-b686-49db-9666-a55292cbe59b-0",
       "type": "image/jpeg",
       "height": 1888,
       "width": 2560
      }
     }
    ]
   }
  },
  {
   "id": "z12zh1gopsqyep5ox04cef0rwqrtsl1ai54",
   "url": "https://plus.google.com/117367546931116283373/posts/THnmvu6e9FT",
   "actor": {
    "displayName": "Max Braun",
    "url": "https://plus.google.com/117367546931116283373"
   },
   "verb": "post",
   "object": {
    "attachments": [
     {
      "objectType": "photo",
      "displayName": "#throughglass, thanks @mattywyattmartin!",
      "id": "117367546931116283373.5876858377843226994",
      "content": "IMG_20130511_153648.jpg",
      "url": "https://plus.google.com/photos/117367546931116283373/albums/5876858374868052977/5876858377843226994?authkey=CPT71f-zl_iToQE",
      "image": {
       "url": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-E_OT7cr5qj4/UY7LjsafuXI/AAAAAAAA1yg/RAEswDK1-iw/w497-h373/IMG_20130511_153648.jpg",
       "type": "image/jpeg",
       "height": 373,
       "width": 497
      },
      "fullImage": {
       "url": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-E_OT7cr5qj4/UY7LjsafuXI/AAAAAAAA1yg/RAEswDK1-iw/s0-d/IMG_20130511_153648.jpg",
       "type": "image/jpeg",
       "height": 1276,
       "width": 1276
      }
     }
    ]
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

This is how I am accessing it with PHP:

```
$posts = json_decode($content);
foreach ($posts->items as $value){
    echo "<b>ID: </b>" . $id . "<br />";
    echo "<b>Name: </b>" . $value->actor->displayName . "<br />";
    echo "<b>Profile URL: </b>" . $value->actor->url . "<br />";
    echo "<b>Post URL: </b>" . $value->url . "<br />";
    echo "<b>Post Text: </b>" . $value->object->attachments->displayName . "<br />";
    echo "<b>Image Small: </b>" . $value->object->attachments->image->url . "<br />";
    echo "<b>Image Full: </b>" . $value->object->attachments->fullImage->url . "<br /><br />";
    $count++;
}
```

For some reason I cannot get the attachment data because it is nested under "object". Is there a fix or a workaround that will work for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo "<b>Post Text: </b>" . $value->object->attachments[0]->displayName . "<br />";
echo "<b>Image Small: </b>" . $value->object->attachments[0]->image->url . "<br />";
echo "<b>Image Full: </b>" . $value->object->attachments[0]->fullImage->url . "<br /><br />";
```

The attachments portion is an array. So you need to access it via it's array index then you can access the properties of the object in the array.